# Zeros in blk00*.dat files

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

When writing a blockchain parser I've found that some blk00*.dat files contain zeros instead of blocks. (I got zero where magic bytes were expected, looked in the file and saw there are more zeros.)

What does it mean? Do I have corrupted chain? How do I fix my parser, so it would interpret the file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zero instead of magic bytes means the end of bictoin block data. just skip the rest of file and follow to next blk-file

by the way. it is better to assemble blk-files for future parsing with old clients (I use 0.8.5) because they put blocks in right order

Comment: I've checked that the block in the next file points to hash of previous one and indeed, it does. Thank you!